# Error on train() function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to learn from an online example and got stuck on one part. Particularly when i use train() function. I got an error saying train isn't a function. I did research and believe train is a function.
The code i copied was : 
    xgb_tree_model =  train(SalePrice~., data=train, method="xgbTree", trControl=control, tuneGrid=grid, metric="rmsle", maximize = FALSE)

The site I am using is http://hamelg.blogspot.com/2016/09/kaggle-home-price-prediction-tutorial.html

Comment: `train` is a function in the `caret` package. You will need to install the `caret` package (once) and load it (every new session) when you want to use it.

Comment: The tutorial uses a dataframe called `train`, but then also uses the `train()` function from `caret`. You might be better off assigning a different name to the dataframe to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check step by step.

1. Check if package is installed. Check using following command.

   `find.package(c("caret"),lib.loc=NULL,quiet=FALSE, verbose = getOption("verbose"))`

   it will show you package path if found else show you error message.
2. If package is not installed, install it by using `install.packages("caret")`
   this will install package.
3. Now load your caret package using `library(caret)`
4. call `train()` function. Now you should not get error message.