# rbind.fill error in train() function in R caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, rbind

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403712/error-on-train-function-in-r) was closed and the solution accepted was to check if the package *caret* was installed correctly. As instructed in the solutions I checked if *caret* package was installed and loaded correctly. I have reloaded the package and it is available in the current session. The following lines using `train(...)` is producing the error:

```
model <- train(
price ~ ., diamonds,
method = "lm",
trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv", number = 10
    , verboseIter = TRUE
))
```

Here I am trying to train and cross validate the famous diamonds dataset on a linear model. However, the following error is observed:

```
Error: All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames
```

It doesn't provide any further information about the error. My warnings are on. Is there any way I can debug this?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Shall I delete the question? Or you can write the comment as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: okay I changed my comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy pasted your code in my console and it worked just fine. Try updating your caret package.